# Converting a List of Base type to a List of Inherited Type

Tags: c#, generic-list

I would be certain that this question addresses something that would have been brought up in a previous question, but I was unable to find it.

There is a method in a C# class that takes as a parameter a generic List of a Base Class.  I need to pass a list of an inherited class and do not know exactly how to do this.  I am getting an error in my attempts.  Below is sample code to illustrated this:

```
public class A
{
   public static void MethodC(List<A>)
   {
       // Do Something here with the list
    }
}
public Class B : A
{
   // B inherits from A, A is the Base Class   
}

// Code utilizing the above method 
List<B> listOfB = new List<B>();
A.MethodC( (List<A>) listOfB );  // Error: this does not work
A.MethodC( listOfB.ToList<typeof(A)>() ); // Error: this does not work
A.MethodC( listOfB.ConvertAll<A>(typeof(A)) ); // Error: this does not work
// how can I accomplish this?  It should be possible I would think
```

Note:  Here is my final working  Method as a reference.  I got an even better solution to my problem, but technically it wasn't an answer to the question, since my question was phrased impropertly.

```
 public static DataTable 
    ObjectCollectionToDataTable<GLIST>
      (List<GLIST> ObjectCollection) where GLIST 
              : BaseBusinessObject
        {
            DataTable ret = null;

            if (ObjectCollection != null)
            {
                foreach ( var b in ObjectCollection)
                {

                    DataTable dt = b.ToDataTable();
                    if (ret == null)
                        ret = dt.Clone();
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        ret.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray);
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: That's the same answer I gave you...

Comment: And it is technically the answer to what you originally asked, as well! :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have linq available you can do

```
var ListOfA = ListOfB.Cast<A>().ToList();
```

Comment: I do not think I have linq, but it worked anyway.  thank you very much for your quick response.

Comment: Possible problem - does MethodC need to modify the list, so that those changes are visible outside of MethodC?

Comment: Glad it worked!  The only reason I believe you have the LINQ extension methods available was the use of ToList in your example.

Comment: now, it doesn't need to modify the list, it foreachs through the collection and calls abstract methods on each one.

Comment: You can skip the '.Cast<A>': var ListOfA = ListOfB.ToList<A>();

Answer (score 9):

You cannot do that. To understand why it is not allowed, imagine what would happen if `Add` was called on a `List<Derived>` after it had been cast to a `List<Base>`.

Also, the answers implying that C# 4.0 will be different are wrong. List will never be modified to allow you to do this. Only `IEnumerable` will - because it does not allow items to be added to the collection.

Update: The reason it works in the solution you've gone for is because you're no longer passing the same list. You're creating a whole new list which is a copy of the original. This is why I asked about modifying the list; if `MethodC` makes changes to the number of items on the list, those changes would be made to a copy, not the original list.

I think the ideal solution for you is as follows:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public void MethodC<TItem>(List<TItem> list) where TItem : A
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
            item.CanBeCalled();
    }

    public abstract void CanBeCalled();
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void CanBeCalled()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling into B");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<B> listOfB = new List<B>();

        A a = new B();

        a.MethodC(listOfB);
    }
}
```

Notice how, with this solution, you can pass a `List<B>` directly to `MethodC` without needing to do that weird conversion on it first. So no unnecessary copying.

The reason this works is because we've told `MethodC` to accept a list of anything that is derived from `A`, instead of insisting that it must be a list of `A`.

Comment: I don't think that is true, it works fine.  My method call works loops through the collection and acts on abstract (override) methods and properties.  I used the code above in a previous response, and it works great. the project is .NET 2.0 with CSC.exe (C#) 3.0 as the compiler.

Comment: I'm guessing you're having difficulty getting this to work? :)

Answer (score 4):

You are addressing the lack of covariance in the current C# version.  Here is one way of doing it:

```
listOfB.Cast<A>();
```

Comment: This only gives you an IEnumerable<A>, not List<A>.

Comment: this works because ((List<A>)listOfB.Cast<A>()) gives me what I want when I explicitly cast it as a List.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer that will exclude any objects in your list of the wrong type. This is a much safer way in my opinion:

```
List<A> ListOfA  = ListOfB.OfType<A>().ToList();
```

The OfType method will exclude items of the wrong derived class where as the Cast will throw an error.