# overriding list result type in java

Tags: java, generics, list, overriding

I would like some variant of this code to compile in java.

```
class X
{
    List<X> getvalue(){...};
}

class Y extends X
{
    List<Y> getvalue(){...};
}
```

Javac (1.6) returns an error because List<Y> and List<X> are not compatible.

The point is that I would like the compiler to
recognize that List<Y> is a compatible return
type to List<X> if Y is a subtype of X.
The reason I want this is to simplify the use of a user-defined factory class.

Note: This question is somewhat like
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686305/converting-a-list-of-base-type-to-a-list-of-inherited-type)
but for java.

Comment: Please format the code so that it is readable.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754756/how-to-cast-a-list-of-inheriting-objects-to-a-collection-of-objects-in-java/2755050 and maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures/2777297

Comment: Fixed it for him :) Just took me four tries... lol.

Answer (score 8):

In Java, the return type of the overriding method has to be covariant with that of the method being overridden.

The class `java.util.List` is not covariant (In fact, no Java class is. This happens because of the lack of declaration-site variance annotations). In other words, `B <: A` doesn't imply `List<B> <: List<A>` (read `<:` as is-subtype-of). Hence your code doesn't typecheck.

---

In Java, you have definition-site variance. The following therefore typechecks:

```
import java.util.List;

class X {
  List<? extends X> getvalue() { return null; }
}

class Y extends X {
  List<Y> getvalue() { return null; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not a compatible type. You can't convert from `List<Y>` to `List<X>` just because `Y` is a subclass of `X`. Consider:

```
List<Banana> bananas = new ArrayList<Banana>();
List<Fruit> fruit = bananas;
fruit.add(new Apple());
Banana banana = fruit.get(0); // But it's an apple!
```

You can use bounded wildcards in Java to express limited variance, giving something which *is* valid:

```
List<? extends Fruit> fruit = bananas;
```

because that will prevent you (at compile-time) from trying to add any extra fruit - the compiler knows it might be invalid.

I would recommend Angelika Langer's [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for further reading about this sort of thing.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf is recommended for anyone who needs to understand how Java generics work.

Comment: The sentence "You can use variance in Java ..." doesn't seem right (if you consider the definition of variance). Maybe you should say "You can use bounded wildcards in Java ..." instead. You could also add that bounded wildcards let you specify the covariance/contravariance constraints on a type-parameter at use-site.

Comment: @one-zero-zero-one: bounded wildcards *give* a form of variance... I'll clarify a bit though.

Comment: @Carlos's link is now at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/generics-tutorial-159168.pdf   There is also a more updated tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/