# Casting generic container of type to container of inherited type?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, inheritance

If I have two classes:

```
public class A { }
public class B : A { }
```

and I create a generic container and a function that takes it:

```
public void Foo(List<A> lst) { ... }
```

I get an invalid conversion if I attempt casting a `List<B>` to a `List<A>`, and instead have to pass it like so:

```
var derivedList = new List<B>();
Foo(new List<A>(derivedList));
```

Is there some way to pass a `List<B>` to this function without the overhead of allocating a brand new list, or does C# not support converting from a generic container of a derived type to its base type?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-list-of-derived-class-objects-to-list-of-base-class-objects

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686305/converting-a-list-of-base-type-to-a-list-of-inherited-type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `List<B>` simply *isn't* a `List<A>` - after all, you can add a plain `A` to a `List<A>`, but not to a `List<B>`.

If you're using C# 4 and .NET 4 *and* your Foo method only really needs to iterate over the list, then change the method to:

```
public void Foo(IEnumerable<A> lst) { ... }
```

In .NET 4, [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) is *covariant* in `T`, which allows a conversion from `IEnumerable<B>` (including a `List<B>`) to `IEnumerable<A>`. This is safe because values only ever flow "out" of `IEnumerable<A>`.

For a much more detailed look at this, you can watch the video of the session I gave at NDC 2010 as part of the [torrent of NDC 2010 videos](http://www.ndc2010.no/index.aspx?id=361621).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.  C# doesn't support co / contra variance on concrete types such as `List<T>`.  It does support it on interfaces though so if you switch `Foo` to the following signature you can avoid an allocation

```
public void Foo(IEnumerable<A> enumerable) { ...
```

Comment: Ah, so that must be why the code `var newList = new List<A>(derivedList)` since it takes an `IEnumerable<A>`... I should be able to change it from `List` to `IList` and it should work fine, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pass list-like things to routines which are going to read them but not write them, it would be possible to define a generic covariant IReadableList<out T> interface, so that an IReadableList<Cat> could be passed to a routine expecting an IReadableList<Animal>.  Unfortunately, common existing IList<T> implementations don't implement any such thing, and so the only way to implement one would be to implement a wrapper class (which could accept an IList as a parameter), but it probably wouldn't be too hard.  Such a class should also implement non-generic IList, also as read-only, to allow code to evaluate Count without having to know the type of the items in the list.

Note that an object's implementation of IReadableList<T> should not be regarded as any promise of immutability.  It would be perfectly reasonable to have a read-write list or wrapper class implement IReadableList<T>, since a read-write list is *readable*.  It's not possible to use an IReadableList<T> to modify a list without casting it to something else, but there's no guarantee a list passed as IReadableList<T> can't be modified some other way, such as by casting it to something else, or by using a reference stored elsewhere.