# How to cast a list of a base type to list of the derived type

Tags: c#, .net, linq

There seems to be a number of questions going the other way, from a derived class to a base class but my issue is how to cast a list of a base type to list of the derived type?

```
public class MyBase {
    public int A;
}

public class MyDerived : MyBase {
    public int B;
}

public void MyMethod() {
    List<MyBase> baseCollection = GetBaseCollection();
    List<MyDerived> derivedCollection = (List<MyDerived>)baseCollection; // Which doesn't work
}
```

Solution I ended up with which is not very elegant.

```
public class MyBase {
    public int A;
}

public class MyDerived {
    public int B;
    public MyBase BASE;
}
public void MyMethod() {
    List<MyBase> baseCollection = GetBaseCollection();
    List<MyDerived> derivedCollection = new List<MyDerived>();
    baseCollection.ForEach(x=>{
        derivedCollection.Add(new derivedCollection(){ BASE = x});
    });
}
```

There must be a better way...

Comment: That isn't a derived class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a List of Base type to a List of Inherited Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686305/converting-a-list-of-base-type-to-a-list-of-inherited-type)

Comment: One cannot simply cast a List<Animal> to a List<Tiger> because a List<Animal> may contain Elephants or Rabbits, and those are illegal return values from List<Tiger>[i].

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the whole reason I was finding this so difficult was my assumptions for MY CODE that the baseCollection only ever contained MyBase objects.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Linq method `OfType<MyDerived>()`, e.g.:

```
List<MyDerived> derivedCollection = baseCollection.OfType<MyDerived>().ToList();
```

It will remove all the items which are not `MyDerived` class though

Comment: This returns 0 items, the baseCollelction only includes items of MyBase.

Comment: Is any of the items object of a `MyDerived` class? If not, then you can not cast an object which is `MyBase` but not `MyDerived` to `MyDerived` class.

Comment: That is the realisation I have come to :(

Comment: If you want to create new `MyDerived` object with `BASE` property set to original object, you can use `List<MyDerived> derivedCollection = baseCollection.Select(myBase => new MyDerived {BASE = myBase}).ToList();`

Answer (score 3):

*Casting* a list of base to a list of derived is fundamentally non-type-safe.

Your code *copies* a list of base to a list of derived.

You can do that more simply:

```
List<MyDerived> derivedCollection = baseCollection.ConvertAll(x => new derivedCollection(){ BASE = x});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;

// with exception in case of cast error
var derivedCollection = baseCollection.Cast<MyDerived>().ToList();

// without exception in case of cast error
var derivedCollection = baseCollection.OfType<MyDerived>().ToList();
```

Comment: cast fails and OfType returns 0 items (the baseCollelction only includes items of MyBase)

Comment: Which is correct, can not cast MyBase to MyDerived ever, my bad no think OO enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class MyBase
{
    public int A;
}

public class MyDerived : MyBase
{
    public int B;

    public MyDerived(MyBase obj)
    {
        A = obj.A;
    }
}


public void MyMethod() {
    List<MyBase> baseCollection = GetBaseCollection();
    List<MyDerived> derivedCollection = baseCollection.Select(x => new MyDerived(x)).ToList();
}
```