# What type is inside a generic container

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

```
public T getValueByName<T>(String name)
{
    if( T is List )
        Object containedType = T.WhatGoesHere()?
...
```

In the above code, I need to know if I can convert a List to whatever type of list is passed in, e.g., `List<Control>`.

Is there a way to interrogate the generic for the contained type?  I could get `List<Control>`, `List<String>`, `List<Form>` etc..

I could split the API to return lists in a separate method where the contained type is passed in, thus requiring the caller to use one method for lists and one for simple types.  Either way they have to know what's coming back, but if there's a smooth way to do what I'm asking about, I'd rather keep the API simple.

Note: this is a solution to the lack of covariance because even though there is an implicit conversion operator defined on the contained type, a cast of List to T fails.  So, in order to follow the solution `listOfB.Cast<A>();` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686305/converting-a-list-of-base-type-to-a-list-of-inherited-type), I need to know to what to cast (what is A).

Thanks!

Comment: You can use typeof(T) and then use reflection to get the generic type arguments

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293905/reflection-getting-the-generic-parameters-from-a-system-type-instance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the type of T from a generic List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-generic-listt)

Comment: I take it this is your question: " I need to know if I can convert a List to whatever type of list is passed in?" If that is the case, then what do you mean because generics allows you to capture any type of object into the method. Can you please provide more information, and a complete code example for what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with `typeof(T)` to get an instance of `System.Type` that represents `T`.
Once you have that, you can check `Type.IsGenericType` to see if it really is a generic and then call `Type.GetGenericArguments()` to see what generic arguments were used.

For example, if `T` was `List<int>` `IsGenericType` would be `true` and `GetGenericArguments()` would return an array containing one element: `System.Int32`

For example, here is a snippet of code I wrote to see if a given type (variable `type`) is some implementation     if `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is not known. It first has to see if it is a generic, then work out whether it has only one argument, determine said argument and see if it implements the interface, given that argument:

```
if (type.IsGenericType)
{
    Type[] genericArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
    if (genericArguments.Length == 1)
    {
        Type proposedEnumerable = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(genericArguments);
        if (proposedEnumerable.IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
```

For reference, see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've ever seen on this site.  Thanks so much!